# correct a malformed javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I send a php array like:

```
$var = array (
0=> 4, 
1=> 6,
2=> 8,
...
```

as json_encode($var);  into the uri and then I receive it into javascript file is still ok here but when I push it into new array like this :

```
 this.patg.push(attd);
```

Is inserted like this below .

```
var attds = ["4,6,7,8,9,5558,5560,5573,5574,5586,5589,5606"]
```

I know I have to find the problem. but

Questions:

1. could you please tell me why this could happends or help me to deal with it.
2. but in any case just for knowledge . how you would add the extra " " surrounding the , that i miss to be an array , or is that crazy idea to fix this?

Comment: Better to focus on 1 question at a time. For question 1, we would have to see the PHP code that generates your array and the question should be tagged as PHP. For question 2, you probably want [`string.split(',')`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: attd and attds?? typo?? Looks like its a String that you are getting. In that case you got to split it with `,` as the delimiter and push them into the array.

Comment: are you sure I'll be able to split it having the "[" at the beginning an the "]" at the end? . Because it doesn't seems to me

Comment: No, you won't. I assumed you were receiving a string. Sorry it was hard to figure out what you were asking before you edited your question. The main part of the answer still stands though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving a string value and you want to use it as an array of integers you should split it into an array first:

```
var receivedData = "4,6,7,8,9,5558,5560,5573,5574,5586,5589,5606";
var dataArray = receivedData.split(",");
```

Afterwards you can use it with another array, however be aware that if you already have a defined array into which you want to push the `dataArray` you shouldn't `push` but `concat` instead.

In other words if you have:

```
var previousArray = [1,2,3];
previousArray.push(dataArray);
```

You will get

> [1,2,3,[4,6,7,8,9,5558,5560,5573,5574,5586,5589,5606]]

meaning that the whole array is pushed onto the 4th position of `previousArray`.

If, on the other hand, you `concat` the arrays will *merge*:

```
var previousArray = [1,2,3];
previousArray.concat(dataArray);
```

> [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,5558,5560,5573,5574,5586,5589,5606]

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: are you sure I'll be able to split it having the "[" at the beginning an the "]" at the end? @Dropout ? . Can't do that.

Comment: You have changed half of your question. I thought you were receiving a string, which when you push into an array leaves you with the result you mentioned in your question..  Anyways the problem is that you need to merge those arrays, not just push it in, because of reasons I mentioned.